# Someone logged in server through ssh using my RSA key

Tags: ssh, rsa

I just got the warning message from hosting provider that my server make outcoming traffic 1.5G to provide DDOS attack on someone host, and they disabled my VPS temporarily.

When I search through auth.log I saw someone logged in with private key, and the only one key on the server is mine. I can't believe someone could stole private key from my computer. Can the hacker somehow logged in without the private key?

Comment: This depends on your server configuration. Have you disabled login with username and password?

Comment: No, it is allowed. For now I disabled RSA authentication so hacker can't login anymore. According to logs he logged in using the key, but not the password. Password is 20 length long, very hard.

Comment: Are you sure that the attacker did not tamper with your logs?

Comment: If it were me, I'd consider reverting to passwords a temporary option until I had updated my key pairs, checked the patches and reviewed the security on where the private key is stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your key are affected by the issue of weak keys, that was generated using the process ID as seed:
https://github.com/g0tmi1k/debian-ssh

Note that this are only dependent on which machine you generated your keys on, NOT the SSH'ed machine.

There is then a possibility that the attacker predicted your key.
Thats why I suggest regenerating the keys, using a debian version where this issue has been fixed, and then replacing the keys in your VPS.